# How to reset timer?

Tags: java, android

I can set the timer as a count down from 10s but the next page the time will start from 0. How can I reset the time as it running every time?

This is my code.

```
private TextView TIMER;
private int Timerr = 10;

public void Show_Next_Quiz(){

        Random random = new Random();
        int Random_Num = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());
        ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(Random_Num);

        Question1.setText(quiz.get(6)+quizCount);

    Right_Answer = quiz.get(0);

    quiz.remove(6);

    Collections.shuffle(quiz);

    iV1.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(0), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV2.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(1), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV3.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(2), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV4.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(3), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV5.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(4), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );
    iV6.setImageResource(
            getResources().getIdentifier(quiz.get(5), "drawable", getPackageName())
    );

        ans1.setText(quiz.get(0).substring(0,(quiz.get(0).length()-1)));
        ans2.setText(quiz.get(1).substring(0,(quiz.get(1).length()-1)));
        ans3.setText(quiz.get(2).substring(0,(quiz.get(2).length()-1)));
        ans4.setText(quiz.get(3).substring(0,(quiz.get(3).length()-1)));
        ans5.setText(quiz.get(4).substring(0,(quiz.get(4).length()-1)));
        ans6.setText(quiz.get(5).substring(0,(quiz.get(5).length()-1)));

        Count_Down();
        quizArray.remove(Random_Num);
}

public void Count_Down(){
    new CountDownTimer(12*1000,1*1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            TIMER.setText(String.valueOf(Timerr));
            Timerr--;
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            TIMER.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TIMER.setText(String.valueOf(Timerr));
        }
    }.start();
```

In the function `CountDown`, i put the `TIMER.setText(String.valueOf(Timerr))` in both (onTick and onFinish) but it cant work. How can i make the timer be 10s. everytime?

Answer (score 0):

make a global variable for `CountDownTimer`.

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

private void timer(){
        countDownTimer =  new CountDownTimer(12*1000,1*1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                TIMER.setText(String.valueOf(Timerr));
                Timerr--;
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                TIMER.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                TIMER.setText(String.valueOf(Timerr));
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

For **Cancel** Timer

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
```

For **Finish** Timer

```
countDownTimer.onFinish();
```

For **Restart/Start** Timer

```
countDownTimer.start();
```

Comment: Owhh But how to use? As i use this it come out      

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.CountDownTimer android.os.CountDownTimer.start()' on a null object reference

this problem how to solve?

Comment: first you need to init countDownTimer. after you can use method.

Comment: ya. I initiate the *countDownTimer* as you teach. but when i type the code *countDownTimer.start()* it giving me that error.